# download android plugins to eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

New at this.  I have downloaded eclipse and I'm trying to download the Android tools for eclipse.  I've found the plug-in, checked the developer tools, and have gotten the message for calculating installation requirements and dependencies.  When I go to install, I get the error message "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found"   Can someone help me figure out why I keep getting this error?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Java JDK? I think that the Java jdk is also required.

Comment: Can't start eclipse without java jdk

Answer (score 0):

All explanations for installing eclipse ADT are quite straight forward here : http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html